# Pandas DataFrame to_excel method shifting header row to right

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am using the Pandas library in Python to try to export the contents of a DataFrame to an Excel file.

I have renamed the headers in the DataFrame to lets say Field1, Field2, Field3 so it looks like this:

```
     Field1  Field2  Field3

0     X        X       X

1     X        X       X

2     X        X       X

3     X        X       X
```

When I export it to Excel I want it to look like this:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3

X        X       X

X        X       X

X        X       X

X        X       X
```

I figured using index=False as a parameter to DataFrame.to_excel() would do just that but instead it is coming out like so:

```
       Field1  Field2  Field3

X        X       X

X        X       X

X        X       X

X        X       X
```

As you can see the headers are shifted to the right.

Here is a picture from the the actual output:

[DataFrame exported to Excel .xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NbN3.png)

Here is my code:

```
def exportToExcel():
    master_inventory_checks_workbook="C:/Users/holmpa3/My Project/Sangeetha_Work_Files_1/INVENTORY_CHECKS.xlsx"
    shutil.copy2("C:/Users/holmpa3/My Project/Sangeetha_Work_Files_1/DATA_DEFS/INVENTORY_CHECKS_TMPL.xlsx", master_inventory_checks_workbook) #copy
    
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UNQ_FIELDS_LIST")
    table=pd.DataFrame(mycursor.fetchall()) 
    
    mycursor.execute("SELECT column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'UNQ_FIELDS_LIST'")
    
    column_names=mycursor.fetchall()
    table.columns=column_names

    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(master_inventory_checks_workbook) #loads workbook
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(master_inventory_checks_workbook, engine='openpyxl' )
    writer.book = book 
    writer.sheets=dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets) 

    print(writer.sheets)
    print(writer.sheets['UNQ_FIELDS_LIST'])

    table.to_excel( writer, 'UNQ_FIELDS_LIST',index=False)

    writer.save()
```

I have been trying to fix this for hours now doing all sorts of things and nothing has worked.

How can I output the DataFrame to Excel so the headers don't shift to the right?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have the exact same issue :/

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was a "hidden" MultiIndex on the rows that was a side effect of how I constructed the dataframe. Removing the MultiIndex with [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's no very clean, but one option is to use empty index for the data frame, like this:

```
table=pd.DataFrame(mycursor.fetchall(),index=['','',''])
```

Probably there is a better solution, but it works